# Cant promote a whole number (integer) field in an infopath 2007 compatible web form

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath

I am using infopath 2010 to work on a pre-existing 2007 form (published to MOSS 2007). It appears that I can add new fields of any type apart from type whole number (integer) and these fields will promote correctly into the existing infopath site content type (uploading as an administator approved template). Any newly created field of type whole number (integer) however fails to appear in the Content Type or Site Column list. Is this a bug in infopath 2010 I am wondering ? I have a workaround to use fields of type double but this seems to be a poor cop out approach.

P.S I am using infopath 2010 because this form is very large and complicated and 2010 has lots of features that aid in designing the form.

P.P.S  The test fields I am adding are brand new and the infopath content type is no longer sub-classed or referenced by any document lists (i.e I have tried all the usual deleting the content type approaches)

Comment: What happens when you create a totally new form and publish it the same way? It appears to me that this bug is caused by your form, however i've never encountered anything similar to this and can't provider a solution either :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that the form had some corrupt internal field mappings (this is not very apparent  until you start hitting these sorts of issues)... some   fields containing missing columnids   (see article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deviations/archive/2010/06/30/help-infopath-forms-and-moss-2007-get-along.aspx).   Solution was to delete all of these mappings in the (manifest.xsf) and re-publish the form to a site content type (update existing site content type) which still contained the correct site column guids (promoting each field with 'this content type').